# 3NF vs BCNF: Example

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

Gday lads,

Ok, so I'm having a database class and I have this example that makes me think that I really didn't fully understand the difference between the two NFs..

I know that

> A relation, R, is in 3NF iff for every nontrivial FD (X->A) satisfied by R at least ONE of the following conditions is true:
>
> (a) X is a superkey for R, or
>
> (b) A is a key attribute for R

and

> A relation, R, is in BCNF iff for every nontrivial FD (X->A) satisfied
>   by R the following condition is true:
>
> (a) X is a superkey for R

Here's the Example:

> R = (A, B, C, D) F = {AB->C, AB->D, C->A, D->B}
>   1. Is R in 3NF, why?
>    If it is not, decompose it into 3NF
>
> ```
> Sol:
> Yes. Find all the Candidate Keys:
> AB, BC, CD, AD
> Check all FDs in F for 3NF condition
> ```

Well, Doesn't C->A cause a violation? C is not a super key and its not trivial, same goes for D->B?

But its not a BCNF:

> 1. Is R in BCNF, why? If it is not, decompose it into BCNF 
>      No. Because for C->A, C is not a superkey. Similar for D->B  R1 = {C,
>      D}, R2 = {A, C}, R3 = {B, D}

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 3NF and BCNF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749913/what-is-the-difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Doesn't C->A cause a violation?  C is not a super key and its not trivial ...

and what about that second condition for 3NF ?  Is A an attribute in some key in R ?

(Hint : the purpose of such exercises is partly also to show you why 3NF isn't a very useful normal form, and the cases where the distinction between 3NF and BCNF matters)